# if, else producing error C2181: illegal else without if

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, boolean, virtual

I have a function with the following definition:

`virtual bool Process(wtdaFileHandler &daHandler, wtdaGather &daGather);`

All code paths in the this function return a `bool` and I am certainly calling this function, not one in a sub class. The following code produces the error in the posting title:

```
wtdaLFDProcess process;

// call some methods to do initialize process and args.

if (process.Process(daLFDFileHandler, daGather));
{
     retval = 0;
}
else
{
    retval = LFD_FILE_LOCK_ERROR;
    cout << "Could not obtain file lock for processing." << endl;
    WTDA_STATUS(3,  "Error...Stopping" );
    return;
}
```

Can anyone explain this? Maybe it's some caveat of C++ which I am unaware of? It makes no sense to me. The error undoubtedly refers to the else. I've built to make sure it's not just the intellisense. This is a Win32 C++ project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to lose this semi-colon:

```
if (process.Process(daLFDFileHandler, daGather));
                                                ^
```

The semi-colon detatches the `if` conditional from the following block, which is then interpreted as a scope, followed by an orphan `else`.

Comment: Oh wow, that's obvious... I've had other problems with this function call so I wasn't really thinking when I got the error (the assignment with the return value has been failing). Thank you,and I will accept when I can.

Comment: @EitanT You have to wait a certain amount of time, ten minute I think.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Most compilers have a warning for this. If you didn't get one or didn't see it you should turn your warning level up and/or treat warnings as errors, so they can't be ignored.

Comment: @bames53 I know, I just made a noob mistake and since I've been having other problems assumed the worse. For example this now compiles, the function returns false, it goes into the else block, I step over it line by line and the code doesn't actually execute! Perhaps it's a problem with the build, I'm debugging remotely, perhaps that code has been disabled?

Answer (score 2):

if (process.Process(daLFDFileHandler, daGather));
remove the ; as it ends if there only

Answer (score 1):

There is unnecessary semi colon in line:if (process.Process(daLFDFileHandler, daGather));

You need to remove it to get desired output.